# Why can't my function find arguments?

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to do a function that performs the bisection method. But I get a lot of errors that I don't understand. The code is:

```
bisection<-function(f,a,b,n=1000,tol=1e-9)
{
  if(!(f(a)<0) && (f(b)>0)){stop}; 
  elseif((f(a)>0) && (f(b)<0)){stop}; 
  for (i in 1:n){
    c=(a+b)/2;
    if((f(c)==0)||((b-a)/2)<tol){return(c)}; 
    elseif(sign(f(c))==sign(f(a)),a<-c,b<-c);
  }
}
```

and I get the following from R:

```
> bisection<-function(f,a,b,n=1000,tol=1e-9)
+ {
+   if(!(f(a)<0) && (f(b)>0)){stop}; 
+   elseif((f(a)>0) && (f(b)<0)){stop}; 

Error: unexpected '{' in:
"  if(!(f(a)<0) && (f(b)>0)){stop} 
  elseif((f(a)>0) && (f(b)<0)){"

>   for (i in 1:n){
+     c=(a+b)/2;
+     if((f(c)==0)||((b-a)/2)<tol){return(c)}; 
+     #elseif(sign(f(c))==sign(f(a)),a<-c,b<-c);
+   }

Error: object 'n' not found

> }

Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

I would be most grateful if someone could point out what I've done wrong.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: what should be the result that you want `bisection` to output?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to correct your function. So it does not result in errors:

```
bisection<-function(f,a,b,n=1000,tol=1e-9)
{
  if(!(f(a)<0) && (f(b)>0)){stop}
  else if((f(a)>0) && (f(b)<0)){stop}
  for (i in 1:n){
    c=(a+b)/2
    if((f(c)==0)||((b-a)/2)<tol){
      return(c)
      }
    else if(sign(f(c))==sign(f(a))){
      a<-c
      b<-c
    }
  }
}
```

but I guess you want another else case in the last else if:

```
bisection<-function(f,a,b,n=1000,tol=1e-9)
{
  if(!(f(a)<0) && (f(b)>0)){stop}
  else if((f(a)>0) && (f(b)<0)){stop}
  for (i in 1:n){
    c=(a+b)/2
    if((f(c)==0)||((b-a)/2)<tol){
      return(c)
    }
    else if(sign(f(c))==sign(f(a))){
      a<-c
    }else{
      b<-c
    }
  }
}
```

Furthermore, it looks like you confused the concept of ifelse with else if.
See for ifelse: https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/ifelse-function
and else if: https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/if-else-statement

Comment: Thank you, the errors now disappeared, but now it seems that if I call the function with arbitrary values for a and b, it only returns c=(a+b)/2 and skip the rest.

Comment: @AnnieFrannie what does your function f looks like? Maybe it always is true already for i =1